Dynamic variable placeholders (e.g., {{section}}) not replaced in HTML when rendering PDF
I'm working on a system that processes Excel files, extracts data, and inserts dynamic variables into an HTML string, which is later rendered into a PDF. The backend uses a regular expression to capture a numeric value (e.g., 94), which I want to insert into the HTML as part of a description. The issue is that the variable placeholders (e.g., {{section}}) are not being replaced with the actual value when the HTML is rendered into the PDF.
Setup:

The regex captures the value correctly (94 in this case), but the
replacement in the HTML fails.
Here is an example of how I use the placeholder in HTML:

<p>
  This area has additional special provisions that may apply to your land.
  Read <a href="https://example.com/special-provisions.pdf">section {{section}} to review.</a>
</p>

In the backend code, placeholder is being replaced using a RegexMatch function, which correctly captures the value (94) but fails to replace {{section}} in the final output:
var description = specialProvision.Description ?? "";
foreach (var key in match.Groups.Keys)
{
    var value = match.Groups[key].Value;
    description = description.Replace($$$$$"""{{{{{{{{key}}}}}}}}""", value);
}

What I’ve Tried:

Using {{section}} in the HTML results in the PDF displaying {{section}} as literal text.
Increasing or decreasing the number of curly braces ({{{{section}}}},
{{{{{{section}}}}}}, etc.) doesn’t help.
The value is captured correctly by the regex (94), but the
replacement isn't happening as expected.

Note:

I cannot modify the backend code. The only place I can make changes is within the HTML.

Is there a known issue with curly braces and templating systems that might affect this replacement in HTML-to-PDF conversion?

What language is this?

You're making it way complicated.  Just do description.replace("{{"+key+"}}", value);

@TimRoberts The thing is I cannot modify the backend code. I am working as a data entry on this project and I can just modify excel. I looked into code and found this.

If the code is incorrect, then someone is going to have to fix it, don't you think?

@TimRoberts Correct. I have to contact the dev tomorrow. I wanted to know if I am doing it wrong or the problem is somewhere in the code.
